# How to solve "Could not find or load main class" running a jar file

Tags: java, jar, ant

Ok so I search high and low for one and a half day's also on stackoverflow and found lots of answers that dit not addres or solve my problem 
I expect this to be a verry basic newby error

I run into a problem making a jar file with ant.

I made a test project 
compiled and bundeld it into a jar file using ant

when i try :
java -cp C:\javaprojects\ant-jar\dist\test.jar com.test.Hello
it works fine

when I try java  C:\javaprojects\ant-jar\dist\test.jar
it fails with this error

Error: Could not find or load main class C:\javaprojects\ant-jar\dist\test.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\javaprojects\ant-jar\dist\test.jar

jar -tf C:\javaprojects\ant-jar\dist\test.jar shows:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/test/
com/test/Hello.class
```

the manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.6
Created-By: 11.0.3+7 (AdoptOpenJDK)
Main-Class: com.test.Hello
Class-Path: .
```

the ant file:

```
    <project name="test" basedir=".">
        <property name="src" location="src" />
        <property name="build" location="build" />
        <property name="dist" location="dist" />

        <target name="compile" description="compile the source">
            <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" />
        </target>

        <target name="dist" depends="compile">
            <jar destfile="${dist}/test.jar" basedir="${build}">
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.test.Hello"/>
                    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
                </manifest>
            </jar>
        </target>
    </project>
```

so what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it's `java -jar foo/bar.jar`

Comment: ..... what can i say this is embarrasing I have been searching in the wrong direction all the time. so thanks a LOT!!!

Answer (score 0):

So to round things up 
Gyro Gearless got the answer in the comment nothing wrong with the code just the call

```
java -jar  C:\javaprojects\ant-jar\dist\test.jar
```

tunnel vision I guess